# Fazer um backup em mais de um banco de dados. c#

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde devo fazer backups e restore automáticos entre banco de dados. Mas quero resolver isso passo por passo.

Por agora gostaria de saber como eu faria uma seleção de vários bancos de dados (Sql Server) e fazer o backup dos mesmos, tentei fazer pelo CheckedList Box do c# mas não obtive sucesso. O código está simples onde ele apenas faz a conexão com a instância e o backup de 1 banco de dados por vez

```
    private void backupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (clbDataBase.Text.CompareTo("") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione um Banco de Dados.");
                return;
            }
            cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cn.Open();
            //sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + cmbDataBase.Text + " TO DISK ='" + locationBox.Text + "\\" + cmbDataBase.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+ ".bak'";
            sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + clbDataBase.Text + " TO DISK ='" + locationBox.Text + "\\" + clbDataBase.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+ ".bak'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Backup executado com sucesso!");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não obteve sucesso, entendido. Mas **por quê?** Digo, qual o problema? O que acontece de errado? O que você você espera que o código faça e o que ele está fazendo atualmente?

Comment: Me perdoe se não ficou claro, sou novo no fórum e as dúvidas as vezes não podem ficar muito claras. Enfim, vamos lá. Eu cheguei a fazer uma inserção de um CheckedList Box, e consigo puxar os dados dos Bancos utilizando o comando clbDataBase.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());. O problema é mesmo selecionando mais de um banco no checked List não consigo fazer o backup dos mesmo. Gostaria de alguma sintaxe ou de qual maneira eu consiga fazer isso.

Comment: Mas por que você não consegue? O que te impede?

Comment: Pois quando faço a seleção de mais de um banco de dados dentro do CheckedList ele apenas faz o backup do primeiro banco que foi selecionado, sendo que desejo fazer o backup de 1,2 ou n bancos que eu selecionar no checkedList.

Comment: Entendido. O checkedList é este `cmbDataBase`, certo?

Comment: LINQ, perdão, pisei na bola, tinha adicionado o código errado no campo de texto. Enfim, coloquei o código correto agora. o clbDataBase é meu checkedList, eu consigo armazenar os bancos nele, mas apenas não consigo fazer o backup em mais de um quando faço mais de uma seleção

Comment: WPF ? terás que percorrer os itens da lista verificando quais estão checados

Comment: Rovann, utilizando um for e verificando qual box de cada linha está preenchido?

Comment: Windows Form. A única dúvida que tenho é, como ficará a condição? Novamente peço desculpa a vocês, estou tendo que aprender o mais avançado, então ainda estou pegando a manha. `for (clbDataBase.Text.CompareTo?)`

Comment: Algum resultado ?

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui, graças as vocês! Muito obrigadão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar passar por todos os itens selecionados no `CheckedList` e fazer a ação.

Algo como:

```
if(clbDataBase.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
{  
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione um Banco de Dados.");
    return;
}

foreach(var marcado in clbDataBase.CheckedItems)
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cn.Open();

    sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + marcado.ToString() + " TO DISK ='" + 
           locationBox.Text + "\\" + marcado.ToString() + 
           "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+ ".bak'";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


MessageBox.Show("Backups executados com sucesso!");
```

Comment: LINQ, tu manda muito cara! Muito obrigado pelo suporte!

Comment: De nada, @MatheusArduino Você pode marcar a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta marcando o **V** abaixo das setas para votar, no lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você utiliza a propriedade `CheckedItems.Count` para verificar se há algum item selecionado,

Abre a conexão com sua base, e percorre os itens selecionados efetuando o processamento que você precisa.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (clbDataBase.CheckedItems.Count ==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione um Banco de Dados.");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                cn.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < clbDataBase.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                {

                    string sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + clbDataBase.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + " TO DISK ='" + locationBox.Text + "\\" + clbDataBase.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".bak'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Backup executado com sucesso!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

ps. Uma dica, Utilize yyyy-MM-dd no nome dos arquivos, pois assim você consegue ordená-los pela data =]

Comment: Rovann, desculpa a demora pelo feedback do código. Quando utilizo `if (clbDataBase.CheckedItems.Count > 0)` e seleciono mais de um banco ele diz que não há banco de dados selecionado. Mas se eu coloco `if (clbDataBase.CheckedItems.Count == 0)` o programa ainda continua apenas fazendo backup de um banco

Comment: eu editei a resposta depois da primeira postagem, confira se está certo

Comment: Rovann, mesmo assim ainda continua fazendo o backup de apenas um banco selecionado no clbDataBase.

Comment: a linha string sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + clbDataBase.CheckedItems[i].ToString() está igual ?

Comment: a linha ficou `sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + clbDataBase.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + " TO DISK ='" + locationBox.Text + "\\" + clbDataBase.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".bak'";`